# subtract variables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I subtract values in two variables. Here is what I have done so far

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @A='select count(abc)
 from x'
 EXEC (@A)
 PRINT @A

 SET @B= ' select count(xyz)
 from  y'

 EXEC (@B)
 PRINT @B

 DECLARE @C INT
 SET @C = CAST(@A AS INT) - CAST(@B AS INT)
 EXEC (@C)
 PRINT @C
```

I am getting conversion error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value

Comment: `@A` is the string "select count(abc) from x", not the result of executing that statement.

Comment: I hope this is a learning experiment and not real code. There is no reason for dynamic sql in what you posted. This whole thing could be a single query.

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to learn sql..Thanks all for the help :) cheers!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you get a conversion error, because the variable is a string. Even if the string is a query, if you execute it you are not storing the result back to your variable. What you need to do is something along the lines of:

```
DECLARE @A INT, @B INT, @C INT;

SELECT @A = COUNT(abc)
FROM x;

SELECT @B = COUNT(xyz)
FROM y;

SET @C = @A - @B;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `@A` and `@B` will hold the sql statements and not the results of them. If you want to run a dunamic sql statement and get some output from it you need to check for [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) where you may define output parameters.

A proper implementation of your code would be the following:

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

SET @SQLString = N'select  @test = count(abc) from x'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@test int OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @A=@test OUTPUT;

SET @SQLString = N'select  @test = count(xyz) from y'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @B=@test OUTPUT;

DECLARE @C INT
SET @C = CAST(@A AS INT) - CAST(@B AS INT)
PRINT @C
```

Another note is that declaring your `@A` and `@B` as `(MAX)` is too much....
It would be better if you would declare them as `INT` and avoid the additional cast:

```
DECLARE @A INT
DECLARE @B INT

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

SET @SQLString = N'select  @test = count(abc) from x'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@test int OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @A=@test OUTPUT;

SET @SQLString = N'select  @test = count(xyz) from y'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @B=@test OUTPUT;

DECLARE @C INT
SET @C = @A - @B
```

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table1')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table1
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table2')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table2
END

CREATE TABLE Table1 (Col1 VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE Table2 (Col2 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES('1'),('2'),('3'),('4')

INSERT INTO Table2
VALUES('2'),('4')
```

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @C INT
DECLARE @ACount INT
DECLARE @BCount INT

SET @A='SELECT @ACount = COUNT(Col1) FROM Table1'
SET @B='SELECT @BCount = COUNT(Col2) FROM Table2'

exec sp_executesql @A, N'@ACount int out', @ACount out
exec sp_executesql @b, N'@BCount int out', @BCount out

SET @C = @ACount - @BCount

PRINT @C
```

**Cleanup:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table1')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table1
END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table2')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table2
END
```